# How to calculate joint distribution by integrating over all possible values of model parameters and observations

Tags: python, joint-distribution, numerical-integration

I was wondering how to calculate the following joint distribution by assuming that $x_i$'s are continuous observations from normal distirbution $N(\mu, \sigma)$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$ and $p(\mu, \sigma)$ is the joint distribution of $\mu$ and $\sigma$:
$$
p(x_1,x_2,..., x_n, x_{n+1}) = \iint {\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{n+1} N(\mu,\sigma)|_{x_j}} . p(\mu, \sigma) \,d\mu \, d\sigma
$$
I know that this can be accomplished by solving the intergration numerically (e.g. with rectangular integration), however, the thing that puzzles me is that the products of $N(\mu,\sigma)|_{x_j}$ would be always zero since the probability of the point $x_i$ in a continuous distribution  $N(\mu,\sigma)$ is zero (or I'm wrong?).

In addition, what is the best method to calculate (or estimate) this distribution in **python**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this looks like deep learning related stuff, maybe an exercise.

$N(\mu,\sigma)|_{x_j}$ is not the probability of a point $x_j$, this is the density of point $x_j$ given the parameters $\mu, \sigma$. The total integral is not the probability either, it is the likelihood of sorts or a density function. The whole thing is in fact never a zero, because the density $N$ of normal distribution is never zero, it can be very small of course.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestion for the implementation in python? I've used `dblquad` for the integration but it takes a lot of time for evaluating a series of let's say 20 observations. I think the slowness of the integration is related to the fact that the p(μ,σ) is calculated using the product of two log-normal distribution but I simply use linear (not exponential) interval for the integrands.

Comment: I'm not sure someone intended to integrate this numerically. They may have written the equation to get across the concept. Multidimensional integration is very difficult beyond 2-3 dimensions, it's heavy computationally. You may want to integrate analytically or re-consider whether you need to integrate at all. If need help on integration though, it's better to post a separate question. There's a chance the question would be considered off-topic and moved to other SE or SO sites

Comment: But this formula comes from a paper in which the authors used numerical integration via a simple quadrature rule. Since the integrands are represented by log-normal distributions, they have used a rectangle rule in which the intervals between interpolation points vary exponentially.
But I don't know how to use the rectangular rule of integration with exponential intervals for the interpolations.

Comment: What was dimensionality?

Comment: The observations have only one dimension.